# Trying to add an object from React to MongoDB collection via axios , but axios POST command not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

i couldent figure out how to pass an object from my react form to my mongodb DB collection ,

the object info iam getting into the onSubmit(thisListGoesToDB) function is :
thisListGoesToDB = { img:"" ,title:"" , date:"" }

EDIT:
i figured out the 404 problem , but now i get a mongoose validation error
(mongoose:validatorError) on cmd
,
couldent get the object thisListGoesToDB into my collection...

React Code(submit function):

```
 const onSubmit = async (thisListGoesToDB) => {

  const options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:5001/create-new-memory',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(thisListGoesToDB)
  };

  axios(options)
  .then(response => {

  }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})

};
```

NodeJS GET Command:

```
app.get("/create-new-memory", (req, res) => {
 
});
```

NodeJS Post Command:

```
       app.post('/create-new-memory' , (req , res)=>
    {           
               const newListing = new List({
      img: req.body.img,
      title: req.body.title,
      date: req.body.date
   }) 
                        newListing.save().then().catch()
                         .then((result)=>res.json(result))
                          .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
                })
```

Mongoose Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ListSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  img: {type: String , required:true},
  title: {type: String , required:true},
  date: {type: String , required:true}


  
});

const List =  mongoose.model("memoryList", ListSchema);


module.exports = List
```

thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "not responding"? Is the backend action invoked? In any case, currently you're not sending any data.

```
const options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:5001/create-new-memory',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(thisListGoesToDB)
};
```

**is not** a valid axios config.

The `body` property is not supported by axios, I suppose you confuse that with the native `fetch` contract. You need to use the `data` property. Axios' `data` property supports plain objects so you're not forced to JSON-ify it. You may ditch the headers as well.

Try this:

```
const options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:5001/create-new-memory',
    method: 'POST',
    data: thisListGoesToDB
};
```

or even cleaner:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5001/create-new-memory', thisListGoesToDB)
    .then((response) => {
        ...
    });
```

**EDIT**:

Also, change this *abomination*:

```
app.post('/create-new-memory' , (req , res)=>
{           
       const newListing = new List(req.body) 
       newListing.save().then().catch()
           .then((result)=>res.json(result))
           .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
})
```

to something like:

```
app.post('/create-new-memory', (req, res) => {           
    const newListing = new List(req.body);

    newListing.save((error, document) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            // Throw error or return error result
        }

        res.json(document);
    });
});
```

I am not sure what you were trying to do with all those empty callbacks but
in your case, you weren't even passing the stored document down the callback chain.

Also, as a general advice, use `;` at the end of your code statements. It is not mandatory, but you're open to a wide range of hard to trace bugs if you don't. Also, it makes the code QUITE easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: thank you , but it is still not working , i think the problem is on my req.body path..

Comment: @matan2288 Show the content of 'thisListGoesToDB' just before you send it with the axios request and what you receive with req.body.

Comment: @matan2288 Also, see my edit, it should resolve the backend action problem.

Comment: i found it , it was a typekey problem , mongoose saw the object as a string , your answer helped me alot tho , thanks for the coding tip , im kinda new in this game :) , i got my solution here tho https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey

Answer (score 0):

In you NodeJS Code, you have to use http method POST, [here is documentation for express post method](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.post.method):

```
app.post('/create-new-memory' , (req , res)=> {  
// ...
// your logic here
}
```

Here is the [documentation for expressjs routing](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).